# RAD of canvas dashboard app winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, canvas, components, widget

I am looking to build an application where the end user can drag-and-drop controls onto a form at run time. I have searched for a lot on this topic but not sure what exactly this type of application is called. I have searched for canvas app, dashboard app, component app, widgets, visual programming, and diagramming. My vision is a bit different from Visual Studio style interface because instead of windows in that I imagine each component is can be dragged onto a surface. I have seen this accomplished using either grid layouts or canvas style layouts. I don't really need "connectors" as one would have in a diagramming but would like the "surface" capabilities.

My questions are:

1. Is there a specific name for an application that allows the user to drag/drop controls onto a surface at run time?
2. What third party, open source, and commercial components provide this capability for WInforms?
3. What third party, open source, and commercial components provide this capability for WPF?
4. I am not experience in WPF. Is this a "built-in" capability of Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Winforms to create a Canvas like surface/structure by adding event handlers to controls when they are clicked and then setting the control's location to the current mouse location by adding event handler in the MouseMove event for the form.

Example code:

```
    bool isDraggable = true;
    private void mycontrolClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isDraggable = !isDraggable;           
    }

    private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDraggable)
        {

            Point newLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            myControl.Location = newLocation;
        }
    }
```

Additional steps would be to add a draggable icon (hit test) region to the control for this purpose (or a mode) and possibly some form of collision-detection like bounding box so that controls would push each other versus overwriting. The final step would be to add a serialization routine to save the locations of the canvas. Also, it may be required to bubble up the events/mouse events.

The other solution would be to create a traditional MDI Winforms application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984330%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The benefit to using the Canvas structure is that the individual controls can be custom drawn and thus "light weight" (real-estate wise) when compared using an MDI container. One could, even, use a design mode to layout the dashboard and then switch to a run-time mode.